# Make a function that overwrites one string with two strings in the beginning and end

Tags: string, scheme, racket, overwrite

I'm using the strange language of Racket to overwrite one string with two others at the beginning and end.

```
(define overwrite (s beg end)...
```

For example, `(overwrite "catapult" "dog" "blah")` should output `"dogablah"`
             `(overwrite "greenbeans" "munk" "grub")` should output `"munknbgrub"`.

Sometimes the overwrite can completely overtake the central word:
`(overwrite "dog" "mouse" "flea")` should output `"mouseflea"`.

The main problem is that I'm only allowed to use three built-in functions to try and solve this problem. (string-length), (substring) and (string-append)

I've tried the following to no avail:

```
(define (overwrite s beg end)
  (string-append (substring s 0 (string-length beg)) ""
                 (substring s (- (string-length s) (string-length end))
                            (string-length s))))
```

I'm allowed to use helper functions and other basic math functions but this is something I've never had to do before. Too bad scheme/racket doesn't have some easy-to-use replace function. 
Thanks in advance! This is as specific as I can get with this pretty much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your one line solution:

```
(define (overwrite s beg end)
  (string-append beg (substring s (string-length beg) (- (string-length s) (string-length end))) end)
```

notice that the following would work:

```
(overwrite "greenbeans" "munk" "grub")
=> "munknbgrub"
```

but the following would fail:

```
(overwrite "dog" "mouse" "flea")
```

The reason is, [`substring`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html?q=substring#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._substring%29%29) only accepts nonnegative integers as arguments. Since the argument

```
(- (string-length s) (string-length end))
```

becomes negative whenever the string length of `s` is smaller than `end`, eg. "dog" vs. "flea", this will raise an exception.

You can resolve this by checking if length of `s` is smaller than the lengths of `beg` and `end` combined, in which case you would simply append `beg` and `end`. eg:

```
(define (overwrite s beg end)
  (let ((l1 (string-length s))
        (l2 (string-length beg))
        (l3 (string-length end)))
    (if (>= (+ l2 l3) l1)
        (string-append beg end)
        (string-append beg (substring s l2 (- l1 l3)) end))))
```

then you will have:

```
(overwrite "greenbeans" "munk" "grub")
=> "munknbgrub"
(overwrite "dog" "mouse" "flea")
=> "mouseflea"
```

Comment: I'll accept this as a good answer however we just learned about conditional statements after the assignment was given out and we were told that we weren't allowed to be used in this particular question.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently figured out it was a one-line answer. Bullcrap!

`(define (overwrite s beg end)
  (string-append beg (substring s (string-length beg) (- (string-length s) (string-length end)))  end))`

I mean if anyone's got a better way of doing this, feel free to share.